# Why moving from one page to another does not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to move from one page to another if I enter the correct username and password. For this Im using the `window.location.href`

But when i tried to use this, it says that the other page was deleted or moved even though both pages are in the same folder

```
if(UN == "a" && PA == "123"){
         window.location.href="<file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/ProudMom/secondPage.html>";
```

Comment: When user enter correct user name and password set form action to redirect to that page

Comment: Off topic, but this is one of those situations where you should use === instead of ==.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(UN == "a" && PA == "123"){
    window.location.href="secondPage.html";
}
```